# Why does C++11 define a non-existing value as a default value?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, default-value, language-design

Below is excerpted from [cppreference link 1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_mode) and [cppreference link 2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16):

```
enum codecvt_mode
{
    consume_header = 4,
    generate_header = 2,
    little_endian = 1
};

template
<
    class Elem,
    unsigned long Maxcode = 0x10ffff,
    std::codecvt_mode Mode = (std::codecvt_mode)0
>
class codecvt_utf8_utf16 : public std::codecvt<Elem, char, std::mbstate_t>;
```

Obviously, `0` is not a well-defined value of enum type `codecvt_mode`. The C++ standard might intentionally leave the default value implementation-defined.

However, I think an implementation-defined default value can be vague to the user.

Why does C++11 define

> `std::codecvt_mode Mode = (std::codecvt_mode)0`

rather than

> `std::codecvt_mode Mode = std::little_endian`

?

Comment: `0` is perfectly well defined for that enumeration type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The enumeration is a set of bit flags that can be combined (via bitwise operations), not values that are selected independently. A value of zero means none of the flags are active (which makes it big endian, and does not consume or generate a BOM).

Answer (score 6):

`0` *is* a valid value for your enum type. According to language standard enum types whose underlying type is not fixed (your case) can represent all integer values representable in a bit-field of sufficient width (sufficient to represent all *named* enum members you declared). The fact that you sometimes need an explicit cast to force all these value into that enum type is just a little inconvenience. This means that `0` is a valid value for any enum type.